# Bash: what is assignment `a=` defined?

Tags: bash

In bash, If I make assignment

```
a=
```

What is `a` now? I am sure a is not `''` string, and not `0`.

I found only below test is true

```
if [ $a = ];then echo 'good';fi
```

Comment: Why are you sure of that?

Comment: After the assignment `a` will have the default value, depend on it's type. 
If `a` is first declared as int `declare -i a`, it is equal to 0. If `a` is first declared as string, or there is no prior declaration, it is equal to ''.

Comment: @linerd then why `if [ $a = 0 ];then echo 'good';fi` and `if [ $a = '' ];then echo 'good';fi` got errors?

Comment: @user15964, if I'm not wrong, the command `if [ $a = 0 ];then echo 'good';fi` will raise syntax error with POSIX-compliant shell (bash included). It will be evaluated as `if [  = 0 ];then echo 'good';fi` because `$a` is an empty string. To avoid that, you need to quote `$a`, or use `[[ ]]` instead of `[ ]`

Comment: @linerd Thank you so much. You are right.`if [ "$a" = '' ];then echo 'good';fi` works

Comment: @user15964  :)))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the empty string.

It's the same as doing:

```
a=''
```

Or

```
a=""
```

Or

```
a=$''
```

Or for that matters:

```
a=''""$''
```

Those `''`, `""`, and `$'...'` are quoting operators to the shell. When you do:

```
a=''
```

You're not assigning a string made of two single quote characters to `$a` but the empty string. Those `''` are superfluous as there's nothing inside them, but that can make your code slightly more legible (make it clearer that you did intend to assign an empty string).

To assign a literal `''` to `$a`, you'd need to quote those special characters like:

```
a="''" a=\'\' a=$'\'\'' a="'"\'
```

Your test command is invalid. In

```
[ $a = ]
```

Since you forgot to quote `$a`, the split+glob operator is applied to `$a`. Since `$a` is empty (but that would be the same if it contained only blanks or newlines with the default value of `$IFS`) that results in no argument to be passed to the `[` command.

So all the arguments `[` receives are `[`, `=` and `]`. For `[`, that's a test to tell if `=` is a non-empty string and it returns true.

What you want here is to pass these arguments to the `[` command:

1. `[`
2. the content of `$a` for which you need `"$a"`
3. `=`
4. the empty string. For which you need `''` or `""`... Passing nothing would mean that no argument is passed to `[` so the 4th argument would be the closing `]`.
5. `]`

So it should be:

```
if [ "$a" = '' ]; then echo '$a is empty'; fi
```

Or:

```
if [ -z "$a" ]; then echo '$a is empty'; fi
```

Comment: The usual test for a set variable is `a=; echo "<${a+-}>"`. It will print <-> for a variable set, even to the empty string. This will print `<>` only: `unset a; echo "<${a+-}>"`, meaning that `$a` in unset.

Answer (score 0):

Variable a equals to empty string.

```
a=

if [ "$a" -eq "" ]; then echo 'good'; fi
```

Output is:

```
$ . tst.sh  
good
```

And for this code:

```
a=

if [ -z "$a" ]; then echo 'good'; fi
```

Output is the same.

Comment: `["$a" -eq ""]` with an empty `$a` becomes `[ -eq ]`, that tests whether `-eq` is a non-empty string. If `$a` contained `foo`, that would become `[foo -eq ]`, and the shell would probably complain that it can't find a `[foo` command. You need `[ "$a" -eq "" ]`. Similarly, you need `[ -z "$a" ]`.

Comment: Yep, you're right. Edited.